# How to Import Custom Font in Vuetify Using Vue CLI 3 Version

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, vue-cli-3

I'm trying to include custom font in Vueitfy project. 
Followed many resources but none of them worked. Vueitfy is overwriting my styles even if used `!important`

In my App.vue

```
<style lang="stylus">
  * {
        font-family: 'SofiaProSoftW01-Regular', Helvetica Neue, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif !important;
  }
</style>
```

In my public/index.html

`<link href="http://db.onlinewebfonts.com/c/47ff3156fe928e750d0468143555356f?family=SofiaProSoftW01-Regular" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>`

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To modify `Vuetify` with `Vue CLI` styles:

Install `stylus-loader` to makes the internal webpack config handle all of them.

```
npm install -D stylus-loader stylus
```

1. Create a stylus folder to storing `main.stylus` the file inside the project and put this code in it:

```
$body-font-family = 'YourFontName';

// main.styl
@import '~vuetify/src/stylus/main';
```

2. Import the new `main.styl` file into your `main.js`:

```
import "./stylus/main.styl";
```

Comment: I think the var is called: `$body-font-family` instead of `$font-body-family`?